# Passing an image location dynamically to Bootstrap-Vue's b-card doesn't seem to work?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

In my project, I have to display a series of images, and I have stored their paths in a configuration object ìmg`:

```
data() {
  return {
    el: "#about",
    img: {
      'buy': '../assets/buy.svg',
     }
  }
}
```

I am using [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) components in my template, and I try to create a b-card for each image.

My problem is, that if I pass the path directly to the `img-src`property, it is displayed. However, if I try to read it from my `img` object, the image is not displayed.

Any hints of how to resolve this?

The following template code snippet illustrates the problem:

```
<div id="lifecycle">
  <!-- prints correct path -->
  <p>{{img['buy']}}</p>

  <!-- shows the picture -->
  <b-card :title="img['buy']"
      img-src="../assets/buy.svg">
  </b-card>

  <!-- can not display the picture :( -->
  <b-card :title="img['buy']"
      :img-src="img['buy']">
  </b-card>
</div>
```

When I inspect the DOM, I can see that in the case where the image path is a string literal, it is resolved into `/static/img/buy.62e6a38.svg`, while when I pass in an expression, it is the non-resolved path, that is passed to the component, `../assets/buy.svg`:

```
<div class="card">
 <img src="/static/img/buy.62e6a38.svg" class="card-img">
 <div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title">../assets/buy.svg</h4> 
 </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
 <img src="../assets/buy.svg" class="card-img">
 <div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title">../assets/buy.svg</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is this some kind of loader issue? 
Any ideas for, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong here. But instead of img['buy'] can you try with img.buy?

Comment: But as I see from data function the path to image property is `img.img.buy`

Comment: Hi @MaxSinev, sorry about the type - the config object is simply img.buy (not img.buy). In my template I print all the paths, and they are correct. When I add the path as a string literal, the picture gets loaded. When I pass it as an expression, the image is not loaded.

Comment: Hi @zapping, tried with `img.buy`and `img['buy']`, but it makes no difference. When I print the value of the expression, it gives the correct path, but the bootstrap component doesnt't pick it up. I am quite puzzled myself, and wonder if it can be a loader issue of some sort.

Comment: Maybe just maybe you need to load an image tag again to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use img path directly in template it will be correctly resolved with vue-loader to `require("path/to/image.png")`, also it translates your asset path to something production related to make it work correctly after build.
If you want to bind path property from code you should help loader to resolve path with `require` or `import`:

```
import buy from "../assets/buy.svg"
//... in component
data() {
   return {
       el: "#about",
       img: {
          buy
       }
   }
}
```

Or with require:

```
data() {
    return {
       el: "#about",
       img: {
          buy: require('../assets/buy.svg')
       }
   }
}
```

Related source: [Vue CLI 3 Docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)